# Trying to save Detail View Data in Master detail App Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, save

I am very new at iPhone Development so I was wondering what I need to do.

I have a Master Detail application for iPhone and have text fields and a date picker and an image in the detail view. All which are defined by the user. I need to know how to save all that information in the text fields(or labels) and in the image view. Will I need to save each text field individualy or can I just do that all at once. Also I realize that when I exit the simulator my new table view cell dissapears. Let me know if you need my code or more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in one of my apps. There is probably a way to do it all at once but I always did each one individually, it takes a while but it works. As for the table view cell disappearing, thats normal. The simulator always starts up as if you just downloaded the app.

P.S. If you like my answer please click the checkmark